# non static method cannot be referenced from a static context problem in Java

Tags: java, non-static

**This is the instructions on what to do :**
Display the names and balances of all three accounts. Using if statements, print the name and
balance of the Bank Account object that has the largest amount of money (based on the values you
chose). You may need to add additional methods to your Bank class (Get Methods).

**This is my code:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Bank
{
    public Bank()
    {
        double checkingBal = 0.0;
        double savingsBal = 0.0;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Problem 1");
        Bank tom = new Bank();
        Bank rohan = new Bank();
        Bank parth = new Bank();
        tom.setChecking(10000);
        parth.setChecking(60000);
        rohan.setChecking(700000);
        larmo();  
    }
    public void setChecking(double val)
    {
        double checkingBal = val;
    }
    public Bank larmo()
    {
        System.out.println(tom.getChecking());
        System.out.println(rohan.getChecking());
        System.out.println(parth.getChecking());
        if (tom.getChecking()>parth.getChecking() && tom.getChecking()>rohan.getChecking())
        {
            System.out.println("Name: Tom, Balance: "+tom.getChecking());
        }
        if (parth.getChecking()>tom.getChecking() && parth.getChecking()>rohan.getChecking())
        {
            System.out.println("Name: Parth, Balance: "+parth.getChecking());
        }
        if (rohan.getChecking()>tom.getChecking() && rohan.getChecking()>parth.getChecking())
        {
            System.out.println("Name: Rohan, Balance: "+rohan.getChecking());
        }
        System.out.println("Congratulations to the richest man in the bank");
    }
    public double getChecking()
    {
        return checkingBal;
    }
    }
```

**I am getting this error:**
non-static method larmo() cannot be referenced from a static context

**Why, and what can I do to fix this.**

Comment: This error will only be the first one you need to fix, given the above code. You really should try to understand the concept of variable scope, instance state and class members.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should change the method to be `public static void larmo()`

`static` because the method does not need access to the Bank instance. This also allows it to be called from static context.

`void` because you do not `return` any value from the method.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot access **non static member** from a **static member** directly.

If you want to access that **larmo method()**:

- Either you should make the larmo method as static
- or, create an instance of Bank class and use that instance to call the **larmo method**